# why is cgconfig.conf not being read on reboot on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, startup, restart, cgroup

I recenty upgraded a release from 12.04 to 14.04, and found out that my cgconfig.conf file is not being read anymore on startup.

The file appears to be correct, in the sense that I can explicitly load it with

```
sudo cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
```

but this doesn't happen automatically on reboot, which means other scripts run on startup fail (because they rely on cgexec with groups defined in cgconfig.conf).

Is there something I need to do to have the file automatically used? (i.e. install some package) 
Do I have to somehow convert this file to some other ?

This used to work correctly before the upgrade, so I am confused as to what might be wrong.

The "cgroup-lite" package, which I think should be responsible for this, is also installed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a regression due to the fix for bug [#1096771](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcgroup/+bug/1096771). There were some init scripts in `cgroup-bin` in 12.04, which were removed in 13.04. The `/etc/init/cgconfig.conf` service file contained this in the `pre-start script` stanza:

```
/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l $CGCONFIG
```

So it was the `cgconfig` service from the `cgroup-bin` package that actually set up your cgroup configuration. `cgroup-lite` hasn't changed much in between these releases, so I assume it isn't meant to read this configuration. I recommend that you open a bug report (and perhaps write a new Upstart service (or copy the old one) since it's unlikely they'll change this in an LTS release).

---

Since 12.04 is still supported, you can use [the Packages index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/cgroup-bin/download) to download the older version of the package. I have reproduced `/etc/init/cgconfig.conf` here for convenience:

```
description "cgconfig"
author "Serge E. Hallyn <serge.hallyn@ubuntu.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]

console output

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/sbin/cgconfigparser || { stop; exit 0; }

    CREATE_DEFAULT="yes"
    CGCONFIG=/etc/cgconfig.conf
    if [ -r /etc/default/cgconfig ]; then
        . /etc/default/cgconfig
    fi

    # If we've already run, don't do it again!
    if grep -q /sys/fs/cgroup /proc/mounts; then
        stop
        exit 0
    fi

    [ -r $CGCONFIG ] || { echo "$CGCONFIG is empty"; stop; exit 0; }

    mount -t tmpfs -o uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755 cgroups /sys/fs/cgroup
    /usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l $CGCONFIG
    if [ "$CREATE_DEFAULT" = "yes" ]; then
        /usr/sbin/create_default_cgroups
    fi
end script

post-stop script
    if [ -x /usr/sbin/cgclear ]
    then
        /usr/sbin/cgclear
    fi
    umount /sys/fs/cgroup || true
end script
```

Comment: thanks, the answer makes sense so I'm accepting it, but if you could point me to a url where I could see how the old service looked like I'd be extra grateful (I'm apparently too stupid to get to the source code from the launchpad issue)

Comment: @riffraff I have updated the answer with a link from where you can download the package. I had made a mistake - the service was called `cgconfig` and not `cgroup`. Sorry about that.