# Where's cgconfig in Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, bug-reporting, cgroup

I'm trying to create a cgroup where I can limit the resources used by Google Chrome after I hit a memory leak that froze my notebook.

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345055/how-to-use-cgroup-in-ubuntu-13-04), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94619/how-to-set-cpu-limit-for-given-process-permanently-cpulimit-and-nice-dont-work?lq=1) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups), but I've found what seems to be a rather grotesque bug in Ubuntu (for a LTS release, IMO):

```
ivan@ivan-ubuntu:~$ sudo service cgconfig status
cgconfig: unrecognized service
ivan@ivan-ubuntu:~$
```

Where's the service file?

I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528258/why-is-cgconfig-conf-not-being-read-on-reboot-on-14-04/529636#529636), that seems related, but unfortunately I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do with the script provided in the answer.

I did try installing the package from the link and it did have cgconfig (I tested the `service cgconfig status` and it worked), but it didn't create the correct files in `/sys/fs/cgroup/`, and when I upgraded the package to the more recent version it removed the `cgconfig` again. I'm so frustrated.

How do I fix this? Also, should I file a bug report in order to improve this? If so, where?

Comment: Have you installed `cgroup-lite`?

Comment: I haven't. I followed the instructions as shown above. Should I? I'll take a look at the package. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that `cgroup-lite` is the responsible for all the mounting. It's broken in Trusty which is why the workarounds are also needed to get them working. I gave up in the end and just added the needed `cgroup` details to startup scripts (`cgcreate`, `cgexec`, etc.), but this isn't ideal.